# unexpected characters in BIND DNS zone slave files

Tags: centos, bind

I have this configuration in my named server's (master server) `/etc/named.conf` :

```
zone "example.com." IN {
    type master;
    file "example.com";
    notify yes;
    allow-transfer {
            172.16.18.2;
    };

};
```

and this configuration in my named server's (slave server) `/etc/named.conf` :

```
zone "example.com." IN {
    type slave;
    file "example.com";
    masters {
            172.16.18.1;
    };

};
```

First I have problem with permission while transferring: `dumping master file: tmp-2ZlzMUSOdT: open: permission denied` but after some search and changing the permission of `/var/named` on server slave using command `chmod g+w /var/named` , there is no problem with transfer `transfer of 'example.com/IN' from 172.16.18.1#53: Transfer completed: 1 messages, 11 records, 356 bytes, 0.005 secs (71200 bytes/sec)`. But `/var/named/example.com` file on server slave contains unexpected characters.

`cat /var/named/example.com` :

```
examplecomMhB�7onecom'sefexamplecomx*W�Q�   :�*04
examplecomv=spf1 a mx ~allEDgoogle-site-verification=-w4hjmB6hYpYT79eg3nG_BkvvIIIk03V56F369855R2b4C
                                                                                                     771046613examplecommaiexamplecom,maiexamplecomMhB�+nsexamplecomMhB�+nsexamplecomMhB�+wwexamplecomMhB�
```

my bind version is `bind-9.9.4-29.el7_2.3.x86_64`.

What is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not have a problem having unexpected characters in your BIND slave files.

After BIND 9.9, DNS slave file format was switched to binary for efficiency reasons.

You can either use special commands to view the slave files or do without the binary format all together and tell BIND to use text format instead.

The binary format optimisation should only be noticed in large setups of BIND, or when using large files for RPZ blacklisting, that often are on the order of hundred of thousands of entries, and can make BIND booting turning from a couple of seconds operation to 1 or 2 minutes.

[Bind 9.9 – Binary DNS Slave file format](http://geekdom.wesmo.com/2014/06/05/bind9-dns-slave-file-format/)

> In order to view the raw binary content, it must be converted to text
>   first:
>
> ```
> named-compilezone -f raw -F text -o example.net.text example.net example.net.raw
> ```
>
> It’s an added layer of complexity, but if you need the microscopic
>   performance boost, that’s the way to go. For those of us that don’t
>   see any issues with the text file format, simply update the named.conf
>   files for your slave zones to include the line:
>
> ```
> masterfile-format text;
> ```